# How to calculate processing time of a file in jmeter for ssh protocol

Tags: jmeter

I am using ssh protocol in jmeter to transfer the sftp file using put command.Now I want to get the processed result using get command.
Finally ,I want to calculate the total processing time each file has taken. The time taken to put the file in a directory and the time taken by the file to procceesed to the destination folder.

Answer (score 0):

Put both requests under [Transaction Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Transaction_Controller), it calculates the cumulative time of its children and reports it as a separate "virtual" Sample Result:

[image]

More information: [Using JMeter's Transaction Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-jmeters-transaction-controller)

Comment: Thanks a lot..Let me try this approach

Comment: I have applied this approach and couldn't find the desired result. Let me put my question this way: I have 10 files that need to process from source directory to destination directory. I have put 10 files to a source directory using jmeter put command under ssh protocol,now our system process these files to destination directory.Now i need to find out our system performance my measuring the time taken by each file to process from source to destination. Please suggest how i can achieve this using jmeter.